# how to add array of object in database using couchbase for item without losing other data

Tags: node.js, typescript, couchbase, sql++

like this

```
{
 id:1,
 name:john, 
 role:[
  {name:boss, type:xyz}, 
  {name:waiter, type:abc}
 ]
}
```

i want to add array of objects to "role" without losing other data, but new data should add to array as a objects.

i have tried with

```
bucket.upsert(key, data, (error: CouchbaseError | null, result: any) => {})
```

where key is a id of document and data is {name:boss, type:xyz}
it shows key already exist.

for db.upsert it replace whole data with new data.

```
var query = N1qlQuery.fromString('UPDATE `myBucket` SET role = ' + '"' + data + '"' + ' WHERE meta().id =' + '"' + key + '"');
```

above code shows role:[object object] in database.

Comment: what version of Couchbase are you using, what version of the Node SDK are you using?

Comment: for couchbase : 2.6.12 and  node: v14.16.1

Comment: 2.6.12 must be the couchbase sdk version, what is the version of Couchbase Server that you're using?

Comment: 7.0.0 (beta) enterprise version on windows

Answer (score 1):

First, I'd think about upgrading to 3.x for the Couchbase Node SDK.

Second, I think what you're looking for is the subdocument API, specifically the "array append" operation. This allows you to make changes to *parts* of a document Here's an [example from the 2.6 docs](https://docs.couchbase.com/nodejs-sdk/2.6/subdocument-operations.html#array-append-and-prepend):

```
bucket
  .mutateIn('customer123')
  .arrayAppend('purchases.complete', 777)
  .execute(function(err, res) {
    // purchases.complete is now [339, 976, 442, 666, 777]
  });
```

I'm not much of a Node/JavaScript developer, but I would assume for your example, it would be something like this:

```
bucket
  .mutateIn('1')
  .arrayAppend('role', theNewRoleYouWantToAdd)
  .execute(function(err, res) {
    
  });
```

Side note: For your N1QL example, the reason that `[object object]` is showing up is probably related to your `data` object returning that as a string. You should also look up "SQL injection", because N1QL code like that could be susceptible. Look into placeholders and [parameterization](https://docs.couchbase.com/nodejs-sdk/2.6/n1ql-queries-with-sdk.html#placeholders).

Comment: thanks for above solution. i have tried that but it is showing ".mutateIn does not exist on type bucket" , not getting exact issue as i m new to couchbase. kindly suggest solution for above issue.  thank you.

Comment: @softwaredeveloper you've reached the limit of my Node/JS knowledge, so I've asked someone else from Couchbase to take a look.